# Express 3 fails to save session changes when uploading files under race conditions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using Express 3 to handle uploads...

```
app.post( "/upload", function( req, res, next ) {
  // do stuff with req.files
  req.session.uploads.push( uploadedFilename )
  res.send( 200 );
});
```

...this works fine, as long as I am only uploading one file at a time.  However if I upload a bunch of files simultaneously, say 10, so that this route gets called 10x in rapid succession, the files will all upload as expected, however the session does not always get updated.

There seems to be something about posting uploads under race conditions that can cause express to not save changes to the session.

Has anyone seen this before / know how to fix it?